# Mongo returning error when diving two columns and setting the value to another added field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to divide two columns and get the result.

My code

```
Collections.aggregate(
        [
          { $project: { _rateValue:1,_rateCount:1 } },
          { '$addFields': { 'avgRating': { '$divide': ['$_rateValue', '$_rateCount'] } } }
        ]
     )
```

My result

```
"error": {
        "ok": 0,
        "code": 16609,
        "codeName": "Location16609",
        "name": "MongoError"
    }
```

Expected Result

```
{
        "_id": "607a5307686f6f38406a8efe",
        "_rateCount": 5,
        "_rateValue": 15,
        "avgRating": 3
    },
```

Comment: Please add sample data and https://mongoplayground.net/ link

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Here is the data sample: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MIAO-Y0qDvy

Comment: Your query is correct, the only problem here is data, that is some records have `_rateValue` or `_rateValue` values as non-numbers, maybe string eg. `"_rateValue": ""`

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar, reverified the column datatype, it is number and not possible to have value as string.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar, Thank you, not exactly the datatype error but it was the structure of data stored. Solved it.

Comment: @DD That's great  :)